# Microsoft Visual Studio stuck in debugging mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, console

Whenever I run my code I am given an error messaging (error msg below) saying It is stuck in debug mode, and the console does not give me a string message for the option I selected.

I have looked for the "enable visual studio" check box other forums have suggested but there isn't one in debug> options. I have not changed any settings so I'm not sure why it's stuck doing this now.

This is the message that shows up in the command prompt

> C:\Users\bob\Desktop\csharp\WhileIterationStatement\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\WhileIterationStatement.exe (process 15644) exited with code 0.
> To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
> Press any key to close this window . . .

I have a while iteration statement,

```
Console.WriteLine("Choose an option:");
Console.WriteLine("1) Option 1");
Console.WriteLine("2) Option 2");
Console.WriteLine("3) Exit");
string result = Console.ReadLine();
if (result == "1")
```

and so on and so forth. It should ask for user input, but it just does nothing.

Comment: You shouldn't look for the "enable visual studio" checkbox but for "automatically close the console when debugging stops".

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? From the message it looks like the program has run and exited but the command window is still open. And it tells you exactly what to do to configure the window to close automatically and what to do to close it at that point. Not clear what your issue is.

Comment: So what happens is I run the code, that message comes up and once I hit a key it goes away and does not run my program. Thanks.

Comment: If that message comes up your program has already finished running.

Comment: "*exited with code 0*". Means your program ran and exited normally. What did you expect it to do that it didn't do? Were you expecting some output or something else?

Comment: I have a while iteration statement, 
            Console.WriteLine("Choose an option:");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Option 1");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Option 2");
            Console.WriteLine("3) Exit");
            string result = Console.ReadLine();
            if (result == "1") 
so on and so forth
it should ask for user input, but it just does nothing.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70571017/edit) the post to update it with the code that can reproduce the problem (not in comments where it can't be formatted and is difficult to read). Please ensure it is complete code as a [mre]. Also include the expected vs actual behaviour.

Comment: Please read the link on how to post code: [mre]. The code needs to be complete. Not just an incomplete code snippet. That is, provide the smallest amount of complete code that anyone can run exactly as shown to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ask for user input, you can refer to the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Choose an option:"); 
        Console.WriteLine("1) Option 1"); 
        Console.WriteLine("2) Option 2"); 
        Console.WriteLine("3) Exit"); 
        while (true)
        {
            string keyChoice = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (keyChoice)
            {
                case "0":
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Choose an option:");
                    Console.WriteLine("1) Option 1");
                    Console.WriteLine("2) Option 2");
                    Console.WriteLine("3) Exit");
                    continue;
                case "1":
                    //To do
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Choose Option 1");
                    Console.WriteLine("Pass '0' To Return To The Main Menu");
                    continue;

                case "2":
                    //To do
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Choose Option 2");
                    Console.WriteLine("Pass '0' To Return To The Main Menu");

                    continue;

                case "3":
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of my test, I hope it is useful for you.
[image]